# Is there a way to update two values using ng-options without using ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down list that I want to update an object when one of the options is selected. This is fine if I only need to update a singular property on the object but in this case I want to update two properties using the two properties in the drop down list of objects.

I could just directly assign the option to the object but then I lose the names of my properties, which I want to keep.

I figured out a way to do this using ng-change and underscore to find the associated value but this gets tedious to do this for each drop down list if I have a lot of drop down lists on my page (which I plan on doing).

Is there any way to do this same functionality using just ng-options? If not, is there a better way so I don't have to repeat the update function for each drop down?

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = [
      {value: '1', text: 'joe'},
      {value: '2', text: 'bill'},
      {value: '3', text: 'ted'},
    ];

  //I want to keep the property names, notice how value matches with number     
  //and text matches with name 
  $scope.item = { 
    name: 'joe',
    number: '1'
  }

  //Is there a way to get this same functionality using ng-options?
  $scope.update = function(item) {
    item.name = _.findWhere($scope.list, {value: item.number}).text;
  }

});
```

Html

```
<select ng-model="item.number"
        ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in list" ng-change="update(item)">
</select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/di7RB2oVKJR57CK1sOPh?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can directly use `$scope.item` object for your `ng-model`, and use the expected object format (`{name: option.text, number: option.value}`) as the value in your `ng-options`, track by a unique property, and let Angular do the rest.

The `track by option.value || option.number` is necessary to match the selection for the initial rendering, where the `$scope.item` initially didn't have `item.value` to compare with, so the `track by` will fallback to the `item.number` for comparison.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = [
      {value: '1', text: 'joe'},
      {value: '2', text: 'bill'},
      {value: '3', text: 'ted'},
  ];

  $scope.item = { 
    name: 'joe',
    number: '1'
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="item"
        ng-options="{name: option.text, number: option.value} as option.text
                    for option in list
                    track by option.value || option.number"></select>

{{item.name}}-{{item.number}}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oKfWRANkkPiS6UHKrjRX

Comment: This will replace the names of the properties in the original object. Notice how the properties in each object are named differently. I want to retain the separate names for each object.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you were saying. But finally I understand that you want to keep them as `item.name` and `item.number`. I have updated my answer. I hope it answers your question :)

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can create **directive** to update model when the value of item number changes.

Updated your [**Plunker code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AgLJu8CPnBz7ohxthOIn?p=preview)

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('customModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.customModel+"."+attr.watchVar, function(new_value){
        scope[attr.customModel][attr.updateVar] = _.findWhere(scope[attr.listName], {value: new_value}).text;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Template:**

```
<select custom-model="item" watch-var="number" update-var="name" list-name="list" ng-model="item.number" ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in list1"></select>
```

Since you will be having multiple `<select>` in single page, I have included additional **attributes** to mention which variable to update:

- **custom-model:** `item` will be used to watch and update attribute.
- **watch-var:** Will watch for changes to `item.number`.
- **update-var:** Updates `name` attribute of `item`.
- **list-name:** `list` will be used for mapping.